# Regex replace multilines in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, newline

I want to replace these line in my AssemblyInfo.cs encoded in UTF-8 with Windows CRLF at the end of each lines

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
=======
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.0")]
>>>>>>> v1_final_release
```

by these

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
```

To do so, I have a powershell script that will parse through all my files and do the replacement.

The regex I prepare in regex101 is [this one](https://regex101.com/r/m7aE7O/2) and works on 101 :

```
<<<<<<<\sHEAD\n\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\("2\.0\.0\.0"\)\]\n\[assembly:\sAssemblyFileVersion\("2\.0\.0\.0"\)\]\n=======\n\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\("1\.1\.0\.0"\)\]\n\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\("1\.1\.0\.0"\)\]\n>>>>>>>\sv1_final_release
```

I can't manage to make the -replace work on the new lines.
But when targeting only `<<<<<<<\sHEAD`, it matches and replacing is performed.

All the following variations failed :

- `<<<<<<<\sHEAD\n\[assembly:` no error no replacement
- `<<<<<<<\sHEAD\r\n\[assembly:` no error no replacement
- `<<<<<<<\sHEAD`r`n\[assembly:` no error no replacement, write-host prints it as 
  `<<<<<<<\sHEAD
  \[assembly:`

It's not about `/gm` or `(*CRLF)`

My powershell instruction  for info :

```
$ConflictVersionRegex = "<<<<<<<\sHEAD\n\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\(`"2\.0\.0\.0`"\)\]\n\[assembly:\sAssemblyFileVersion\(`"2\.0\.0\.0`"\)\]\n=======\n\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\(`"1\.1\.0\.0`"\)\]\n\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(`"1\.1\.0\.0`"\)\]\n>>>>>>>\sv1_final_release" 
$ConflictVersionRegexTest = "<<<<<<<\sHEAD`r`n\[assembly:" 
$fileContent = Get-Content($filePath)   
$filecontent = $filecontent -replace $ConflictVersionRegexTest, $AssemblyNewVersion
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($filePath, $fileContent, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

What am I missing ? Why is it not replacing ?

Many thanks

Comment: Why use regex instead of just a simple replace? Also .Net uses its own little regex. Seems you made your regex in PCRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on feedback from Poutrathor (the OP), there were two problems:

- The **primary problem** was that **`Get-Content($filePath)`** (which should be written as
  `Get-Content $filePath`<sup>[1]</sup>) **reads the file *line by line***, which results in an *array of lines* when captured in a variable.
  **`-replace` then operates on each input line *individually***, which means that the line-spanning regex won't match anything.

  - Solution: **Use `Get-Content -Raw` (PSv3+) to read the file *as a whole*** into a *single*, multi-line string.
- Secondarily, you mention needing to replace the ***regex* newline (end-of-line) escape sequence (`\n`) (LF)** with its ***PowerShell* string-interpolation counterpart (`` `n ``)** - note that PowerShell uses `` ` ``, the *backtick*, as the escape character:

  - Note that that is only necessary in the *replacement* string, in order to create *actual, literal* newlines (line breaks) *on output* - as opposed to using regex construct `\n` for *matching* newlines.
  - However, **on Windows, newlines are typically CRLF *sequences***, i.e., a CR (`\r`, `` `r ``) immediately followed by a LF (`\n` / `` `n ``) - i.e., **`\r\n`/ `` `r`n ``** - whereas on Unix-like platforms they are *just* LF, **`\n` / `` `n ``**.

    - If you're not sure which style of newlines given input has, **use `\r?\n` to match newlines in a cross-platform-compatible manner**.
      If you don't care what specific newlines the input has, this is safe to use methodically, as a matter of habit.
  - Therefore:

    - In your *regex*, while in your case you can *choose* between `\r\n` and `` `r`n ``, note that:

      - `` `r`n `` only works in *double-quoted* `"..."` strings.
      - **It is generally preferable to use literal, *single-quoted* strings to store regexes** - which **requires use of `\r\n` (Windows) / `\n` (Unix) / `\r?\n` (platform-agnostic)** - so that there's no confusion over which parts of the string PowerShell interpolates up front vs. which parts are interpreted by the regex engine.
    - In your *replacement string*, use `` `r`n `` inside `"..."` to create actual newlines.

---

As an **alternative to using escape sequences** to represent newlines, **you can use [here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6#here-strings) to conveniently define multi-line strings with actual newlines (line breaks)**, as shown in [Paweł Dyl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52829063/45375), but there's a **caveat**:

- Here-strings invariably have the same style of newline *as the enclosing script file*, which means that:

  - **A regex based on a here-string will only match if the input happens to have the same style of newlines as the *script file*.**
  - A replacement string based on a here-string will invariably use the script file's newline style.

---

<sup>[1] Your call looks like a .NET *method* call and while it happens to work in this case, such syntax confusion should be avoided: PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like *shell* commands: without parentheses (`(...)`) and with *whitespace*-separated arguments.</sup>

Comment: So is it how community answer are made ?  :0 

Many thanks for the in-depth explanation. Powershell is tricky.

Comment: My pleasure, @Poutrathor. PowerShell is ... uh ... powerful, so it can definitely get tricky. One of the problems here is that two unrelated worlds mingle: PowerShell's string interpolation and (.NET) regular expressions. What you do mean by community answers?

Comment: I see - thanks, @Poutrathor. In case you weren't just joking: I don't think that this particular answer is a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

See following demo:

```
$newText = @'
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
'@

$src = @'
<<<<<<< HEAD
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
=======
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.0")]
>>>>>>> v1_final_release
Other lines and second instance
<<<<<<< HEAD
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
=======
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.0")]
>>>>>>> v1_final_release
Some other lines
'@

$src -replace ('<<<<<<< HEAD\s+',
    '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("2\.0\.0\.0"\)\]\s+',
    '\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\("2\.0\.0\.0"\)\]\s+'+
    '=======\s+'+
    '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("1\.1\.0\.0"\)\]\s+',
    '\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\("1\.1\.0\.0"\)\]\s+'+
    '>>>>>>> v1_final_release'),$newText
```

Also, make sure your contents are read as one large string. This can be achieved using `Get-Content $path -Raw` or `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path)`.

Comment: Here-strings with actual line breaks are definitely convenient, but in a regex the caveat is that they invariably use the enclosing script file's style of newlines (line endings), which may or may not match the input's.